# Given a matrix A of $4 \times 5$ and $\text{rank}(A)=2$ proposition.

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

As per the title,

Can I say that 'The first two rows of $A$ are non-zero'? Is this statement always true?

Comment: Hints: How many rows of $A$ can be zero? Does rearranging rows change the rank?

Comment: @Théophile, rearranging the rows does not change the rank. But I am unsure of how many rows of A can be zero. I only know that the rref of A must have 2 zero rows. Please advise.

Comment: Okay, suppose that $A$ has two zero rows. If you order the rows to put them at the top, then what?

Comment: @Théophile, assuming I have this matrix: [0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0; 1 1 1 1 2; 1 1 1 1 3]
By calculating the RREF of that matrix, I will get a rank of 2. But is this thinking correct?

Comment: That is indeed a $4 \times 5$ matrix of rank $2$, and its first two rows are *not* non-zero. The statement is therefore false.

Comment: @Théophile, but would I be wrong to say that, the first two zero rows are redundant / not a proper equation, and hence that 4 x 5 matrix isn't quite correct?

Comment: Well, a matrix isn't an equation, it's just a collection of numbers in a box. (Matrices can correspond to coefficients of a system of equations, but the matrix itself is not the same thing as the equations.) From a certain point of view, the first two rows could be considered redundant information (e.g., they don't contribute to the row span), but they're still *there*. Here's a metaphor: consider all the points $(x,y)$ in the plane. Compare those to all the points $(x,y,0)$ in 3d space. The $z$-coordinate is "redundant" in a way, but $(x,y)$ and $(x,y,0)$ are still different animals.